# Flask celery app vs a normal Flask app (how to make them work together simultaneously)

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a Flask Celery app which instantiate the celery instance.
I understand that from the .py file point of view, I could add a normal Flask route to the same .py file, and I would need to run the same code twice:

1. Run the worker:

   % celery worker -A app.celery ...
2. Run the same code as normal Flask app:

   % python app.py ...

My question is: if the normal Flask app is truly separate process from the Celery app, then how could I manipulate the running celery instance from a Flask route to do something like :

```
  celery.control.purge()
  celery.control.inspect() etc ???
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import random
import time
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, flash, redirect, \
    url_for, jsonify
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)

# Celery configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@celery.task
def send_async_email(msg):
    """Background task to send an email with Flask-Mail."""
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


@app.route('/purge', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def purge_tasks():
    ## want to do stuffs with the running celery instance, e.g:
    ## doing:
    ##    celery.control.purge()
    ##    celery.control.inspect()
    ##
    ## BUT HOW??

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've been searching the internet for answer, but none of the answers specifically answers this question.

Thank you so much for any help/pointer.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but if your flask app is a URI, can't you make a call from within the celery task to consume it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the goal is to be able to do some manipulation (listing, inspecting) of tasks by referring to the active celery instance through a Flask route.
i.e: I think I should do it by referring to this celery instance:
   'celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])'

But, how can I refer to that instance from a Flask route (a different process) than the 
    `celery worker -A ...` instance ?
?

Maybe I'm thinking this in the wrong direction, but how can we inspect the current active celery queue from a Flask route?

Comment: If it helps, accept the answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: As written above, you don't have a way to queue up any tasks: your only route is 'purge_tasks()' where you want to inspect / eliminate tasks from the queues.

A second route where you call 'send_async_email.delay(msg)' would allow users to enqueue tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This, http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application, looks like it will answer your question. Read Application and then Calling the Task. What you need to do is save your Flask app as a "task" as described in the doc and then pass that task into a Celery instance, incidentally called "app" too.